# Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'xyz.testimonials' doesn't exist (SQL: select * from `testimonials`)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

[SOLVED] I'm not a pro on Laravel. Just started with web development. I was asked to make changes on an existing project which I downloaded from c Panel. On the server, the project was working fine. But after downloading it I'm getting the following error and not quite sure what's going on.

> SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'xyz.testimonials' doesn't exist (SQL: select * from `testimonials`)

After downloading the project I can the following

> php artisan cache:clear
>
> composer update
>
> php artisan migrate
>
> php artisan db:seed

The following the TestimonialController.php file

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Testimonial;

class TestimonialController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $testimonials = Testimonial::all();
        return view('dashboard.testimonials.index')->withTestimonials($testimonials);
    }

    public function create()
    {
        return view('dashboard.testimonials.create');
    }

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate(['testimonial_text'=>'required']);
        $testimonial = Testimonial::create($request->all());
        if($testimonial)
        {
            $this->success('Testimonial added successfully');
        }
        else
        {
            $this->error();
        }
        return redirect()->back();
    }

    public function edit(Testimonial $testimonial)
    {
        return view('dashboard.testimonials.edit')->withTestimonial($testimonial);
    }

    public function update(Testimonial $testimonial,Request $request)
    {
        if($testimonial->update($request->all()))
        {
            $this->success('Testimonial Updated Successfully');
        }
        else
        {
            $this->error();
        }
        return redirect()->route('dashboard.testimonials.index');
    }

    public function destroy(Testimonial $testimonial)
    {
        if($testimonial->delete())
        {
            $this->success('Testimonial Deleted Successfully');
        }
        else
        {
            $this->error();
        }
        return redirect()->back();
    }
}
```

Testimonial.php

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Testimonial extends Model
{
    public $guarded = [];

    public function allTestimonials()
    {
        return self::all();
    }
}
```

Comment: This is just a side note. Don`t run composer update on live project unless all agreed to do so. This will update all packages and dependencies and can break the application. Instead run composer install.

Comment: Just to be sure - have you updated your local `.env` and config to match your local environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure about **testimonials** table **exists** in your **xyz** DB. If you've created table with another name then you've to define it in the model.

Let say, You've taken a table name as testimonial. then in your model, the protected field will be,

```
class Testimonial extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'testimonial';
}
```

Comment: Hi ! Thanks for your response. The following is the Testimonial.php file,
php
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Testimonial extends Model
{
    public $guarded = [];

    public function allTestimonials()
    {
     return self::all();
    }
}

Comment: what is your table name? testimonials? if no then whatever it is, put `protected $table = 'yourtablename';` above `public $guarded`

Comment: the person who was working on didn't create a table for 'testimonials'. I guess i have to create the table first? if so should i do it from phpMyAdmin?

Comment: No, Using migration you can create it. `php artisan make:migration create_testimonials_table --create=testimonials`. The person who didn't followed migration then go with manually as phpmyadmin.

Comment: That's why I mention to check the table testimonials is exists.

Comment: Hey man, thanks a ton! You practically saved my life. Owe you big time.

Comment: Select the answer if helped from that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199052/discussion-between-dilip-hirapara-and-i-antonov).

Answer (score 2):

There is two way of table define in Laravel.

- model class name (testimonial) = singular and table
  name(testimonials) = plural , Kindly please check if `testimonials`
  is available or not in your database. whenever you don't define
  `$table` into model, it means Laravel automatic search for table.
- you have to manually add `$table` into Model fileas below. whenever you are not
  creating table name in plural form as following first rule.

  **protected $table = 'testimonial';**

Comment: Actually I'm not a questioner, I'm who given answer before you.